# Тег header по ширине страницы

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Прошу помощи с тегом `header`, отображается не во всю ширину, остаются поля по бокам:[image: цвет тега body по бокам]
На картинке видно, что по бокам от блока, есть цвет тега `body`.
Перерыл кучу сайтов и не смог найти решение, вот код:

```
CSS:
    header 
{
    width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
}


Разметка:
<header>
<nav>
        <center><img src=CAB&CO.png alt=CAB&CO></center>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить следующий css код: `body {margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```